# chai expect(res.body) fails consistently

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai

Response status passes and fails under my control.  But I can't see to get the expect(res.body) test to pass.  Route displays exactly as programmed when viewed in the browser.  but mocha/chai test for testing what is rendered in the browser always fails.  What am I doing wrong??
health-check route code:

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();   // eslint-disable-line new cap
// GET /health-check - checking for basic server reaction
router.get('/health-check', (req, res) =>
    res.status(200).send('CONGRATS')
);
export default router;
```

mocha test:

```
it('should return 200 and res.body of OK', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .get('/api/health-check')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
                expect(res.body).to.equal('CONGRATS');
                return done();
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.  I had to console log the response and then dive into that until I got it to respond correctly.  In my sample above, it was returning an empty set or null.  My code that tends to answer my issue is:

```
.end(function(err, res) {
      if(err)
         return done(err);
      console.log(res.text);
      expect(res.text).to.equal('CONGRATS');
      return done();
```

my original idea was that I had to target the ".body" of the response to test against it.  Doesn't appear to be the case here.